# Грамотное использование Admob в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, admob, unity3d-android

Есть код который показывает рекламу при нажатии на кнопку, но с большой задержкой,как можно избежать данной проблемы?

Вот основной код

```
    string adUnitId = "...";
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;


  public void GameOver()

    {
         interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        interstitial.LoadAd(request);
        interstitial.OnAdLoaded += onLoaded;

    }
   public void onLoaded(object sender,System.EventArgs args)
    {
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, всё банально - вызывайте `LoadAd` при входе в игру, например :) сейчас вы отправляете запрос, потом ждёте пока выкачается реклама и только потом её показываете.

Лучше всего вызвать загрузку при входе в игру, на фоне оно подкачает и закеширует рекламу, а когда вам потребуется - вы проверите загружена ли уже реклама и покажете её, если да, а после показа вызовете загрузку ещё раз.

Точно гарантировать не могу, но, плагины площадок, вроде бы, умеют кешировать рекламные ролики и если ролик был скачан, но не был показан - то при следующем запуске оно возьмёт его, а не начнет качать сначала.